# What happens to the iron throne between the House of Dragon timeline and the Games of Thrones timeline?

Tags: game-of-thrones, props, house-of-the-dragon

As we can see from the *House of the Dragon*, the iron throne looks different from the one we see in the Games of Thrones. In addition to all the melted swords that form the chair, there are lots more to both the left and the right, looking like small bushes.

Do we know what happens to the additional vertical standing swords? As the Iron Throne, as we see from the Games of Thrones does not have them.

[image]

Comment: Probably removed in an attempt to forget the Targaryen dynasty.

Comment: You only need a couple of King's Hands or beloved princesses to trip on the steps before you figure out why they're a really bad idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [twinfinite](https://twinfinite.net/2022/08/why-does-the-iron-throne-look-different-house-of-the-dragon/)

> Ryan Condal added in the same interview:
>
> > “It’s as iconic as a lightsaber in Star Wars. What we wanted to do is honor that, but also tell the story of a more decadent time, and also communicate that 200 years has passed. If you look very closely, you’ll see that the original throne is there. It’s just added to and augmented, which suggests that history changes things at some point in the intervening time.

So basically they tried to make the throne as accurate as possible and only explain the change that a lot can happen in 200 years.

Just like in Game of Thrones they are changing things from books so they can retcon this change also in the show we have to wait and watch if they show Robert's rebellion being the cause for the change or if anything else happens in these 200 years.

Comment: FWIW this version of the Iron Throne is more accurate to the book's version; still some way off but more accurate nonetheless.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think it's more like how much it's possible. As if they really make like book then showing interactions will be dificult

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of different layers to the answer, both in-canon and real-world. In-canon, we haven't yet heard anyone discuss it, mainly because all of the "later" shows were made earlier and didn't know how to address the discussion. We can assume it'll happen post-Dance, or anywhere else in the intervening 200-ish years. It seems logical to assume that the swords may have been removed at the same time that the array of dragon skulls were moved to the basement area (Robert's Rebellion after-action).

Real-world, the production crew had more resources this time and wanted to build a "new" Iron Throne that is closer to the book, while still visually matching the Throne as seen in the "later" Game of Thrones. Therefore, the core Throne itself is largely unchanged, but an accessory array was made around it. This lets the show insert any desired later change to match the GoT show version via a single throwaway line like "I removed the array of swords, too many pages and maids have tripped and died while bringing my tea."

Comment: Isn't that the point to hurt people with the Iron Throne? It is a sign of un-worthiness if someone is cut. I totally get you point. But having an un-comfortable chair and a dangerous path is a really good reminder to the ruler and the subjects.

Comment: @YuZhang that *was* the point, when the throne was made.  But over the course of a couple hundred years and more than a dozen rulers, priorities and values change.

Comment: @YuZhang It's only supposed to be dangerous to the ruler who sits in it.  All those extra swords make it dangerous to everyone else in the room...